# Is it possible to change the DataGrid column what the column are dynamic?

Tags: wpf

i need to create dataGrid that each of his column contain textBox and comboBox.
But my dataGrid column is created on the start of the application - and by reading some config file ... the application know how many column to create and what is the header name of each column.

I don't know even how to create the possibility that each of those dynamically will contain TextBox and ComboBox ( i want to do it somehow from the xaml >

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Why dont you use a DataTemplate for for dataGridColumn?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DataGridTemplateColumn and bind the TextBox text and ComboBox itemssource properties accordinglein order to use a custom template.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ContentsToTransfer}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"></ComboBox> 
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid>
```

This [link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/) may help you to understand it well.